# How to set timezone when creating sites using New-PnPSite

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, modern-experience, communication-site

I'm currently using this command to create new SharePoint modern communication sites:

```
New-PnPSite -Type CommunicationSite -Owner me@acme.com -SiteDesign Blank -Lcid 1044 -Title "My site" -Url https://acme.sharepoint.com/sites/my_site
```

I've yet to find how to set the timezone for new sites, as there doesn't seem to be no `timezone` flag. Is there anything I'm missing here? How does others set timezone for new sites?

Comment: try [this](https://capacreative.co.uk/2018/11/19/create-communication-sites-with-a-specific-primary-language-using-pnp-powershell/) and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use use New-SPOSite to create new SharePoint modern communication sites with timezone:

```
New-SPOSite -Url https://acme.sharepoint.com/sites/my_site -Owner me@acme.com -Template "SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0" -StorageQuota 2048 -Title "Communication" -TimeZoneId 13 -LocaleID 1044
```

References:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/06/sharepoint-online-create-site-collection-using-powershell.html

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/new-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: You could accept the answer if it helps you:)

Answer (score 2):

Using PnP-PowerShell, you can do it like below:

```
$adminUrl = "https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com"
$newSiteUrl = "https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/Pensaerniaeth" 
$ownerEmail = "<your.name@your.email.com>"

$siteTitle = "Pensaerniaeth"                # Translates to "Architecture" - Bing Translator
$siteTemplate = "SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0"      # Communication Site Template
$lcid = 1106                                # Welsh (https://capa.ltd/mui-lcids)
$timeZone = 2                               # London (https://capa.ltd/sp-timezones)

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $adminUrl -NoTelemetry
New-PnPTenantSite -Template $siteTemplate -Title $siteTitle -Url $newSiteUrl -Lcid $lcid -Owner $ownerEmail -TimeZone $timeZone
```

**Reference**:

[Create Communication Sites with a specific primary language using PnP PowerShell](https://capacreative.co.uk/2018/11/19/create-communication-sites-with-a-specific-primary-language-using-pnp-powershell/).

Comment: Thansk, but New-PnPTenantSite seems to create classic sites only, while I'm looking to create modern sites.

Comment: I have tried using this command to create communication site and it works fine. try it and let me know if you found any issue (don't get confused because of documentation).

Comment: Thanks, it did in fact work. Strange, because when I tried it some days ago I got a classic site. I assume it's the "template" flag that made the difference, in that perhaps the command defaults to classic site when no flag i provided (which was the case for my test a few days ago). "New-SPOsite" seems to work fine as well though.

Comment: How can I GET the `TimeZone` value returned for a single site and all sites in a tenant?  Ideally, I want to run a query that returns all sites that do not have a specific timezone id.  I am looking at this reference (https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPTenantSite.html) and when running `Get-PnPTenantSite -Identity $identity -Detailed` I still only get 3 values returned `Url`, `Template` and `LocaleId`.   Not sure if it makes any difference, but the site in this case is a Teams SharePoint site.